# Possible to write automation script for Excel with web-api

Tags: excel, visual-studio, api, automation

Bear with me, for I am a complete noob in terms of programming, scripts, automation, APIs, etc., so there's bound to be some stuff that may be confusing/not possible. Ifmy question is too broad/not suited for this board/website, please let me know and I'll take it down.

I'm looking to write a script for my business, probably in something like Visual Studio or the likes (at least that's what it seems like, reading online). It would be an automation script for Excel.

**The scenario is:**
I have an Excel document with about 8000 rows that needs to be categorized, this is done by just  putting in some data in a new column. The new column can be called B. The information of this new column is dependent on the information of an existing column, column A. The information for column B is retrieved by going to an online search engine, inputting data from A, retrieving a 6-digit code and converting the code into a standardized category.
The website offers a web api with a base url and what seems to be all the bells and whistles of an api (AFAIK, I've never seen any other ones).

**My question is:** would it be possible to write a script in Visual Studio or the likes, which is able to retrieve information from an Excel column, request information based on said column from the api, retrieve some a 6-digit number from the api, convert said number to a standardized category, and then input it into another excel column? And would it even be possible to learn this in a realistic time frame with my current expertise (which is close to none)?

I appreciate any answers and advice, and thanks for reading if you've made it down this far.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is too broad and is likely to lead to opinion-based answers. There are several languages that may accomplish this task. Which one to use is opinion based. If you are a complete noob, you got 2 options: invest pretty much time in learning a language or hire a developer.

Comment: See the answer @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns gave: please e.g. specify the what API you're talking about. As an extra thought: you could probably do this in Excel with VBA, no need for an outside programme like Visual Studio and a lower entry level imho.

Comment: Hi @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns and Koen Rijnsent. Apologies for not having noticed your answers, thanks a lot for both them. Seems you might be right, FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, I guess it's a cost-benefit question in the end. I guess it's also a question of if it would make sense to take a chance with a project like this; if the script would work properly as I imagined. But I guess these are all things I need to find out with myself. Again, thanks for your answer. Are there 1-2 languages you reckon could do this task?

Comment: @KoenRijnsent do you need the API link or what specifications do you need in terms of specifying the API? Okay, thanks for that. I might need to look into VBA-scripting. The only worry I would have is that a VBA script is able convert numbers to fixed categories after they are fetched from the API.

Comment: https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/web-scraping-with-vba They have several examples, also how to scrape "multiple web pages" which you can translate as "using an API".